# WinForms ListView - get source object from selected string item

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am building a simple language learning helper application in WinForms. One of its modules is a dictionary. It consists of "Sets" and words are stored in a Set. User can create a new Set of words and store some of them in it.

I'm printing all the words from selected one or several Sets in a `ListView` with columns. Upon checking a Set or Sets in `CheckedListBox` the List clears and prints words (as string variables).

Trouble comes when there are few Sets checked with their words listed, and user wants to edit one of the listed words. I cannot use indexes (such as `index` of List item equals to word item in a Set), as those List string items are from different Sets.

Is there any way get a source object from a `ListView` item? I have not added objects to the list but only some of their variables, but are they somehow connected?

Thank you for your help.
Cheers!

EDIT: Explaining why to me setting a `Tag` is not a solution:
All the Sets are stored in a `List<DictionarySet> dictionarySets`. Every Set containts a `List<Word> words` where words are stored.

How do I fill the ListView:

```
private void UpdateList()
        {
            wordsListView.Items.Clear();
            List<Word> currentSetWordList;

            foreach (DictionarySet ds in setCheckedListBox.CheckedItems) //List<DictionarySets> dictionarySets inserted, DisplayMember set to its Name property

            {
                currentSetWordList = ds.words;
                foreach (Word w in currentSetWordList) 
                {
                    ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem("--"); //for now a string, later an enum
                    newItem.Tag = ds;
                    newItem.SubItems.Add(w.GermanTranslation); //string property
                    newItem.SubItems.Add(w.PolishTranslation); //string property

                    wordsListView.Items.Add(newItem);
                }
            }
        }
```

In this case the program loops through each Set and its word list and prints the words. Their tag is DictionarySet everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Tag` property on the `ListViewItem`. The Tag property:

> Gets or sets an object that contains data to associate with the item.

In short, when you create each item of the list view, you could add your object as the tag. This way you'll be able to get it back when the user selects an item.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've already learned that but it does not solve the issue: every Set is a `DictionarySet` object, and they are stored in a `List<DictionarySet>`. When I tag ListView items, all of them get `DictionarySet` tag so they do not differ.